# Insufficient permissions for web.config

Tags: iis-7, web-config

According to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055) (method 2, item 6) I'm supposed to add *computername\IIS_IUSRS* as the role allowed to read my *web.config* file.

I'm not sure if it's true, though, because:

1. I've seen other web sites on the current server that don't have that set in *security* tab but still are accessible
2. more importantly, I still get the error 500.19 *related config data invalid* with extension *config file insufficient permissions* (0x80070005).

(At this point I'm only trying to serve a static HTML page, before I'll go on and also deliver web services.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check **every** part of the directory tree in your setup. Make sure that every directory, subdirectory and file that you're trying to access, in fact, has the group IIS_IUSRS defined on your local machine (or the server, in fact). I'm betting my left ear that you'll find a part that hasn't.

The error you mentioned - 0x80070005 - means **precisely that**.

In case you still can't find the source of the issue, remove the whole directory tree and redo the whole setup process. Maybe there's some access right that's catched, then.

I just tested it on my system and I could cause the error you're describing by removing permissions of IIS_IUSRS from a subdirectory.